# Optional parameter value in Symfony's main config.yml

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to write something like that in my app's main `config.yml`:

```
my_section
  some_value: %local_value%
```

Where the param `local_value` would be taken from the `parameters_local.yml` file. However, I would like this value to be optional - if the application user doesn't provide the `local_value` parameter in his `parameters_local.yml`, I would like it to be set to null.

If I leave the `config.yml` the way I have provided it above and try to omit the `local_value` from `parameters_local.yml`, I get the following error message:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]  
You have requested a non-existent parameter "local_value".
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Add `local_value` to `parameters.yml(.dist)` with empty value?

Comment: As I said - I would like it to work without modifying the `parameters.yml`

Comment: Did `my_section`Key refers to a bundle configuration? If it does, you can set default parameter value in your bundle configuration tree.

Comment: That's right, however I would like to have an option to override the default bundle configuration from the parameters file. If provided - use the one from parameters. If not - use the default from bundle configuration.

Comment: Why don't you want to modify that file?

Comment: you could do a specific environment for this as `config_local.yml` that

Comment: @Crozin - because I want this configuration value to be optional and what sense would it make if I had to provide a value for it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use parameter at all. It's up to the developer to decide what he or she wants to be defined as parameter and what not.

1. In your configuration define this value as optional:

   ```
   $treeBuilder->root('my_section')
       ->children()
           ->scalarNode('some_value')->defaultValue('XYZ')->end()
       ->end()
   ;
   ```
2. Let user decide what is most appropriate:

   ```
   # config.yml
   my_section: ~

   ---

   # config.yml
   my_section:
       some_value: ABC

   ---

   # parameters.yml
   my_section_some_value: 123

   # config.yml
   my_section:
       some_value: %my_section_some_value%

   ---

   # config.yml:
   parameters:
       my_section_some_value: 321

   my_section:
       some_value: %my_section_some_value%
   ```
3. You application/library SHOULD NOT depend on any of above solutions.